# ReplaceAll String java regex

Tags: java, android, regex, replaceall

I have a string that contains the following:

```
"Hello my name is (0.9%) and (15%) bye (10.5%) also (C9, B6)"
```

I want to replaceAll so I get rid of the brackets containing percentages but not the other numbers like so:

```
"Hello my name is and bye also C9, B6"
```

Currently I have this but it removes all my numbers, Any idea how I could fix it:

```
.replaceAll("[\\([0-9]\\%)]","");
```

Comment: Your regex doesn't make sense. You're escaping one parenthesis but not the other, and you're only matching a single digit. And why is the `%` escaped?

Comment: Not sure I'm struggling with it at the moment :(

Comment: What happened to the parentheses at the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
"Hello my name is (0.9%) and (15%) bye (10.5%) also (C9, B6)".replaceAll("\\((?:\\d|\\.)+%\\)", "")
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JqzgPj/1)

This here also deletes a single whitespace after each parenthesized percentage:

```
"Hello my name is (0.9%) and (15%) bye (10.5%) also (C9, B6)".replaceAll("\\((?:\\d|\\.)+%\\) ", "")
```

Gives:

```
Hello my name is and bye also (C9, B6)
```

Comment: Do you know how I could also expand on that and remove parentheses  if there is a comma inside so: `"Hello (bye, hello) again (hello)"` would turn into `"Hello bye, hello again (hello)"`

Comment: Try `"Hello (bye, hello), and then (a, b,c) foo, bar (C9, B6)".replaceAll(" \\([a-zA-Z ,]+\\)", "")`. It will remove only parentheses with word-like stuff inside, and leave the numbers alone. (checked, should work now)

Comment: Thanks but basically I need to remove incomplete parenthesis such as `"(hello"` and `"bye)"` and leave `"(hello)"` alone, any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "incomplete parentheses"? Does the "(C9, " piece in "(C9, B6)" count as "incomplete"? This seems to be increasingly far away from the original question. You might want to ask another question. Comments just aren't very good for that, you can't indent code here etc.

Comment: Sorry, I cant ask another question I am limited to 1 per day. Basically I want to remove parentheses that are not complete "(hello" and "hello)" would be "hello" and "(hello)" would be ok

Comment: @KyrilKhaltesky Well, if the restrictions are there, then they probably make sense... I'll just leave you with `"(hello and hello) would be (hello)".replaceAll("(?:\\(([a-zA-Z]+)(?= ))|(?:(?<= )([a-zA-Z]+)\\))", "$1$2")` and the hint that you should look up "positive lookahead" and "positive lookbehind" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the outer brackets and add matching to digits before and after an optional dot.

```
.replaceAll("\\([0-9]+?\\.?[0-9]+?\\%\\)", "");
```

Note: You can change the "+" to "*" if you want to allow a leading or trailing dot.

Comment: Do you know how I could also expand on that and remove parentheses  if there is a comma inside so: `"Hello (bye, hello) again (hello)"` would turn into `"Hello bye, hello again (hello)"`

Comment: Sorry, comments are not the best for formatting. `final Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\(([\\w\\s]*?,[\\w\\s]*?)\\)");`
`final Matcher matcher = regex.matcher("Hello (bye, hello) again (hello)");`
`System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("$1"));` This creates a capture group inside the parentheses, then replaces that match with the version without the parentheses.